# New user of Maven requesting help deciphering dependency for openam tomcat 6 agent

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, openam, opensso

I'm attempting to build an OpenAM (11.0) 3.2.0 tomcat agent. I have successfully built, using Maven, the 11.0 version of the base product. The agent however has some dependency that I'm missing. I'm assuming its a tomcat 6 jar file that 'must' be placed in a specific directory.

**Could you help me decipher the pom.xml and error message?**

The error:

```
...
Downloading: http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/maven-central/org/forgerock/openam/
openam-installtools-launcher/11.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots/org/forgerock/openam/
openam-installtools-launcher/11.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (793 B at 8.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.607s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 25 17:15:16 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jee-agents-tomcat-v6: Could not resolve
dependencies for project org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-tomcat-v6:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-sdk:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:6.0.36 (provided), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), 
javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), javaee:javaee-api:jar:5 (provided), 
commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4 (provided), org.forgerock.openam:openam-clientsdk:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT (provided), 
org.forgerock.openam:openam-installtools:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT (provided), 
org.forgerock.openam:openam-installtools-launcher:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT (provided), 
com.sun:tools:jar:1.5 (system?)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-sdk:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact 
org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents:pom:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT in forgerock-snapshots-repo 
(http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots) -&gt; [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Dev/openam/11.0/openam-agents/jee-agents/jee-agents-tomcat/jee-agents-tomcat-v6
```

The pom.xml:

```
$ cat pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 *
 * Copyright 2013 ForgeRock AS.
 *
 * The contents of this file are subject to the terms of the Common Development and
 * Distribution License (the License). You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License.
 *
 * You can obtain a copy of the License at legal/CDDLv1.0.txt. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permission and limitations under the License.
 *
 * When distributing Covered Software, include this CDDL Header Notice in each file and include
 * the License file at legal/CDDLv1.0.txt. If applicable, add the following below the CDDL
 * Header, with the fields enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying
 * information: "Portions copyright [year] [name of copyright owner]".
 *
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Parent Project -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.forgerock.openam.agents</groupId>
        <artifactId>jee-agents-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Component Definition -->
    <name>OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat v6</name>
    <description>OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat v6</description>
    <artifactId>jee-agents-tomcat-v6</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jee-agents.properties>../../jee-agents.properties</jee-agents.properties>
    </properties>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Specification-Title>OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${project.version} - ${maven.build.timestamp}</Specification-Version>
                            <Specification-Vendor>ForgeRock</Specification-Vendor>
                            <Implementation-Title>OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version} - ${maven.build.timestamp}
                            </Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Vendor>ForgeRock</Implementation-Vendor>
                            <Built-By>${user.name}</Built-By>
                            <Build-Jdk>${java.version}</Build-Jdk>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                            <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                            <Create-On>${maven.build.timestamp}</Create-On>
                            <SVN-Revision>${svn-revision.revision}</SVN-Revision>
                            <!-- TODO Add License to Manifest -->
                            <License/>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-sdk</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.forgerock.openam.agents</groupId>
            <artifactId>jee-agents-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.36</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
$
```

As I look at these files I can't help but think there is some other configuration file that specifies the information I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

-Dennis

Comment: A snapshot is never the latest stable release, the latest stable J2EE agents are built from

https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/JEEAgents-3.3.0/openam-agents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Closure. I modified the pom.xml within :

The SVN Tag JEEAgents-3.3.0/openam-agents/jee-agents/pom.xml

I modified this section to become:

```
    <modules>
        <!-- OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agent Modules -->
        <module>jee-agents-sdk</module>
        <module>jee-agents-agentapp</module>
        <module>jee-agents-tomcat</module>
<!--        <module>jee-agents-jboss</module>
        <module>jee-agents-jetty</module>
        <module>jee-agents-appserver</module>
        <module>jee-agents-weblogic</module>
        <module>jee-agents-websphere</module>
        <module>jee-agents-jsr196</module>
-->
        <module>jee-agents-sampleapp</module>
        <module>jee-agents-distribution</module>
    </modules>
```

Once I commented out those modules, I was able to issue the previous command and get this result:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-timestamp-plugin:1.0:create (default) @ jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-svn-revision-number-plugin:1.6:revision (default) @ jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO] inspecting C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-distribution\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6
[INFO]
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) @ jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (tomcat-v6-assembly) @ jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/tomcat-v6_KitAssembly_Descriptor.xml
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6:pom:3.3.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6:pom:3.3.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6:pom:3.3.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6:pom:3.3.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6:pom:3.3.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] Building zip: C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-distribution\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6\target\Tomcat-v6-7-Agent-3.3.0.zip
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy-build_date.js) @ jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:analyze-only (analyze) @ 
jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO] Skipping pom project
[INFO]
[INFO] --- checksum-maven-plugin:1.0.1:artifacts (generate-checksum) @ 
jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ 
jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-distribution\
jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6\pom.xml to C:\Documents and 
Settings\Clasmir\.m2\repository\org\forgerock\openam\agents\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6\
3.3.0\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6-3.3.0.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-distribution\
jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6\target\Tomcat-v6-7-Agent-3.3.0.zip to C:\Documents and 
Settings\Clasmir\.m2\repository\org\forgerock\openam\agents\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6\
3.3.0\jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6-3.3.0.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents ....................... SUCCESS [16.644s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents AgentSDK .............. SUCCESS [13.740s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents AgentApp .............. SUCCESS [2.774s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat ................ SUCCESS [0.080s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Tomcat v6 ............. SUCCESS [5.318s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp ............. SUCCESS [0.170s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp Web Servlets  SUCCESS [0.581s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents SampleApp Tomcat ...... SUCCESS [0.681s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Distribution .......... SUCCESS [3.035s]
[INFO] OpenAM JavaEE Policy Agents Distribution Tomcat v6  SUCCESS [3.445s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47.109s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 27 14:20:45 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/58M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
$


Thanks for the help.

-Dennis



On Thu, Mar 27, 2014 at 1:01 PM,  wrote:

> What version of Maven are you using? I am using v3.0.5 and these 
> missing dependencies came up as warnings so the build succeeded. 
> Alternatively you could just create some dummy files to match the 
> missing dependencies or alter the top-level pom to not build those 
> modules.
> 
> 
> Thanks
> 
> Mark
> 
> 
> On 28/03/2014, at 5:40,  wrote:
> 
>> Is it possible that steps like this are still required?
>> 
>> Granted these were for ant based builds:
>> 
>> 
>> https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/j2eeagents_303_stable/opensso/products/j2eeagents/README 
>> 
>> 
>> 2.3.2 Obtaining libraries for WebLogic 10.0
>> Follow these steps to obtain the libraries for BEA WebLogic 10.0:
>> 2.3.2.1 Install BEA WebLogic 10.0 server
>> 2.3.2.2 Copy weblogic.jar and api.jar both from the lib directory of 
>> the server
>> installation(for example from /bea/wlserver_10.0/server/lib) into
>> the opensso/products/j2eeagents/extlib/weblogic/v10 directory of this 
>> workspace
>> 2.3.2.3 Copy the com.bea.core.weblogic.security_2.0.0.0.jar from the
>> modules directory of the server installation(for example from 
>> /bea/modules)
>> into the opensso/products/j2eeagents/extlib/weblogic/v10 directory of 
>> this workspace.
>> 
>> 
>> 
>> 
>> On Thu, Mar 27, 2014 at 12:13 PM,  wrote:
>> 
>>> Thank you Peter for responding. You are a huge help.
>>> 
>>> To be safe, I created a new directory :
>>> 
>>> /cygdrive/c/Dev/openam/JEEAgents-3.3.0
>>> 
>>> And I used a 1.6 version of SVN to download all of this:
>>> 
>>> https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/JEEAgents-3.3.0 
>>> 
>>> I then went to this directory:
>>> 
>>> /cygdrive/c/Dev/openam/JEEAgents-3.3.0/openam-agents/jee-agents
>>> 
>>> I issued this command:
>>> 
>>> $ mvn -am -pl 
>>> jee-agents-distribution/jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 clean 
>>> install
>>> 
>>> and I get this error:
>>> 
>>> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>>> [ERROR] The build could not read 3 projects -> [Help 1]
>>> [ERROR]
>>> [ERROR]   The project 
>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-weblogic-v10:3.3.0 
>>> (C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-weblogic\jee-agents-weblogic-v10\pom.xml) 
>>> has 4 errors
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> weblogic:com.bea.core.common.security.api:jar must specify an 
>>> absolute path but is 
>>> /var/tmp/extlib/weblogic/v10/com.bea.core.common.security.api_1.0.0.0_5-1-0-0.jar 
>>> @ line 103, column 25
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> weblogic:com.bea.core.weblogic.security.auth:jar must specify an 
>>> absolute path but is 
>>> /var/tmp/extlib/weblogic/v10/com.bea.core.weblogic.security.auth_1.0.0.0.jar 
>>> @ line 110, column 25
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> weblogic:com.bea.core.weblogic.security:jar must specify an absolute 
>>> path but is 
>>> /var/tmp/extlib/weblogic/v10/com.bea.core.weblogic.security_1.0.0.0_5-1-0-0.jar 
>>> @ line 117, column 25
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> weblogic:weblogic:jar must specify an absolute path but is 
>>> /var/tmp/extlib/weblogic/v10/weblogic.jar @ line 124, column 25
>>> [ERROR]
>>> [ERROR]   The project 
>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-websphere-common:3.3.0 
>>> (C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-websphere\jee-agents-websphere-common\pom.xml) 
>>> has 1 error
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> websphere:com.ibm.ws.runtime:jar must specify an absolute path but 
>>> is /var/tmp/extlib/websphere/v61/com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar @ line 
>>> 84, column 25
>>> [ERROR]
>>> [ERROR]   The project 
>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-websphere-v61:3.3.0 
>>> (C:\Dev\openam\JEEAgents-3.3.0\openam-agents\jee-agents\jee-agents-websphere\jee-agents-websphere-v61\pom.xml) 
>>> has 1 error
>>> [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for 
>>> websphere:com.ibm.ws.runtime:jar must specify an absolute path but 
>>> is /var/tmp/extlib/websphere/v61/com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar @ line 
>>> 109, column 25
>>> [ERROR]
>>> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
>>> the -e switch.
>>> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug 
>>> logging.
>>> [ERROR]
>>> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible 
>>> solutions, please read the following articles:
>>> [ERROR] [Help 1] 
>>> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> On Thu, Mar 27, 2014 at 6:14 AM, Major Péter wrote:
>>> 
>>>> Hi,
>>>> 
>>>> I hope you've checked out the correct tag for building 3.3.0 JEE 
>>>> agents:
>>>> https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/JEEAgents-3.3.0/ 
>>>> 
>>>> To build the tomcat agent run the following command from the 
>>>> jee-agents dir:
>>>> mvn -am -pl 
>>>> jee-agents-distribution/jee-agents-distribution-tomcat-v6 clean 
>>>> install
>>>> 
>>>> cheers,
>>>> Peter
>>>> 
>>>> 2014.03.26. 14:12 :
>>>>> Hello,
>>>>> 
>>>>> I hope this the right place to ask.
>>>>> 
>>>>> I've built 11.0 successfully but I am having difficulty building 
>>>>> the
>>>>> tomcat agent.
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> /11.0/openam-agents/jee-agents/jee-agents-tomcat/jee-agents-tomcat-v6
>>>>> 
>>>>> I have built successfully:
>>>>> 
>>>>>     jee-agents-sdk
>>>>> 
>>>>> When I issue the command "mvn -U -DskipTests=true clean install" 
>>>>> within
>>>>> the tomcat6 directory, I get this error which I'm assuming is 
>>>>> because I
>>>>> have not placed the tomcat 6 jar files somewhere for maven to find 
>>>>> them.
>>>>> 
>>>>> Here is the error:
>>>>> 
>>>>> Downloading:
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/maven-central/org/forgerock/openam/openam-installtools-launcher/11.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
>>>>> Downloaded:
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots/org/forgerock/openam/openam-installtools-launcher/11.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
>>>>> (793 B at 8.6 KB/sec)
>>>>> [INFO]
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>>> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>>>>> [INFO]
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>>> [INFO] Total time: 4.607s
>>>>> [INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 25 17:15:16 EDT 2014
>>>>> [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/16M
>>>>> [INFO]
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>>> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jee-agents-tomcat-v6: 
>>>>> Could
>>>>> not resolve dependencies for project
>>>>> 
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-tomcat-v6:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT:
>>>>> Failed to collect dependencies for
>>>>> [org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-sdk:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT
>>>>> (compile), org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:6.0.36 (provided),
>>>>> javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided),
>>>>> javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), 
>>>>> javaee:javaee-api:jar:5
>>>>> (provided), commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4 (provided),
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam:openam-clientsdk:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
>>>>> (provided),
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam:openam-installtools:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
>>>>> (provided),
>>>>> 
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam:openam-installtools-launcher:jar:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>>>>> (provided), com.sun:tools:jar:1.5 (system?)]: Failed to read 
>>>>> artifact
>>>>> descriptor for
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents-sdk:jar:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT: 
>>>>> Could not
>>>>> find artifact 
>>>>> org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents:pom:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT
>>>>> in forgerock-snapshots-repo 
>>>>> (http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots )
>>>>> -> [Help 1]
>>>>> [ERROR]
>>>>> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven 
>>>>> with the
>>>>> -e switch.
>>>>> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug 
>>>>> logging.
>>>>> [ERROR]
>>>>> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible 
>>>>> solutions,
>>>>> please read the following articles:
>>>>> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException 
>>>>> $ pwd
>>>>> 
>>>>> 
>>>>> /cygdrive/c/Dev/openam/11.0/openam-agents/jee-agents/jee-agents-tomcat/jee-agents-tomcat-v6
>>>>> 
>>>>> I'm not sure what to do.
>>>>> 
>>>>> -Dennis
>>>>> 
>>>>>
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
    OpenAM-dev mailing list
    OpenAM-dev@forgerock.org 
    https://lists.forgerock.org/mailman/listinfo/openam-dev

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not able to retrieve one of the dependency you need on the repository http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots. Try to explore it with a web browser to be sure it's not there. If not, you'll have to find another repository with it or the source code of the dependency and install it on your local repository with 'mvn install'.

The missing dependency is: org.forgerock.openam.agents:jee-agents:pom

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A bump for replying.